# OpenLDAP cannot connect saslBind

Tags: c++, openldap

My workstation has Ubuntu OS 18.04. I use the ldapcpp library from OpenLDAP-2.4.47 in my Qt project for authorization on MS ActiveDirectory server. The code works fine.

```
LDAPControlSet* ctrls=new LDAPControlSet;
ctrls->add(LDAPCtrl(LDAP_CONTROL_MANAGEDSAIT));
cons->setServerControls(ctrls);
LDAPConnection *lc=new LDAPConnection("dc.mydomen.local",389);
lc->setConstraints(cons);
lc->bind("CN=username,OU=Programmer,OU=IVO,DC=mydomen,DC=local", "password",cons);
```

My workstation is in the domain.

```
username@kubuntuit01:~$ sudo net ads testjoin
Join is OK
username@kubuntuit01:~$ sudo net ads keytab list
Vno  Type                                        Principal
  2  des-cbc-crc                                 HOST/kubuntuit01.mydomen.local@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  des-cbc-crc                                 HOST/KUBUNTUIT01@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  des-cbc-md5                                 HOST/kubuntuit01.mydomen.local@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  des-cbc-md5                                 HOST/KUBUNTUIT01@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96                     HOST/kubuntuit01.mydomen.local@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96                     HOST/KUBUNTUIT01@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96                     HOST/kubuntuit01.mydomen.local@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96                     HOST/KUBUNTUIT01@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  arcfour-hmac-md5                            HOST/kubuntuit01.mydomen.local@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
  2  arcfour-hmac-md5                            HOST/KUBUNTUIT01@MYDOMEN.LOCAL
```

But i cannot connect using the saslbind method using the code:

```
LDAPAsynConnection * sas;
sas = new LDAPAsynConnection();  
sas->init("dc.mydomen.local",389);
sas->saslBind("KERBEROS","uid=HOST/KUBUNTUIT01,cn=VIVEYA.LOCAL,cn=gssapi,cn=auth",cons);
```

or

```
sas->saslBind("GSSAPI","uid=HOST/KUBUNTUIT01,cn=VIVEYA.LOCAL,cn=gssapi,cn=auth",cons);
```

In debug mode in the debugger, the message string contains the text: "*80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0904DC, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 57, v1db1*". I tried different authorization options, I don’t know what to try next.

thank

Comment: Define 'cannot connect'.

Comment: You can edit it all you want but until you provide an error message your post is just a waste of space and time.

Comment: Have you considered looking up LDAP error code 57?

Comment: This is not an error code, the error code is indicated in another variable in the debugger and is 49. This is "LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS". I understand that there is an error in the incorrectly specified authorization data, but I have read the OpenLDAP documentation and cannot understand what data should be indicated when using the saslbind (GSSAPI) mechanism.